# Using Swift and CoreData - users logging in

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

So I am creating an iOS application and want to allow users to log in and out/register. I am doing this using core Data and currently my program allows users to register, but the data isn't saved so when they try and log in, it says incorrect username/password, in other words, the program isn't recognizing the fact that the user already input their information when creating/registering their account and as a result cannot load the information they input and won't allow the user to log in. This is the code I have for when a user clicks the register button - please help:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class RegisterPageViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var userEmailTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var userPasswordTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var confirmPasswordTextField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func registerButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    let userEmail = userEmailTextField.text
    let userPassword = userPasswordTextField.text
    let userConfirmPassword = confirmPasswordTextField.text

    if (userEmail.isEmpty || userPassword.isEmpty || userConfirmPassword.isEmpty) {

        displayMyAlertMessage("You haven't filled out all the fields.")
        return;

    }

    if (userPassword != userConfirmPassword) {

        displayMyAlertMessage("Passwords do not match.")
        return;


    }

    var appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
    var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

    var newUser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Users", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject

    context.save(nil)



    var successAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Successfully registered.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { action in
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
    successAlert.addAction(okAction)
    self.presentViewController(successAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)





}




@IBAction func haveAnAccountButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}




func displayMyAlertMessage(userMessage:String) {

    var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert!", message: userMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)

    alert.addAction(okAction)

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}





/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you already have in your *.xcdatamodel file Entity 'Users' with Attributes 'name' and 'password', you need to store data from textField, for example:

```
...
    var newUser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Users", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject

    newUser.setValue(userEmail, forKey: "name")

    newUser.setValue(userPassword, forKey: "password")

    context.save(nil)
...
```

Comment: So I tried what you said and it still doesn't register the fact that I registered. It says incorrect username or password.

Answer (score 0):

SWIFT 4

We Can Create A Login And SignUp In Swift 4 Using Core Data

Here I am Going to create a New project In Swift 4 With Xcode 9 And Follow Me With An Example Task For Core Data

Create New Project With  Select Use CoreData

Create an Entity -User
Add fields - name, age,password,email….Plz Select All the fields type with String

Design Storyboard With Apropriate objects….

Create Login,signup,UserDetails,logout VC’s

Import CoreData For Apropriate Classes

For Connect Views We can Use StoryboardId And Segue For the Views

Create LoginVc

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var nameTextCheck: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var passwordTextCheck: UITextField!
    var context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func signUPButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "User")
        let searchString = self.nameTextCheck.text
        let searcghstring2 = self.passwordTextCheck.text
        request.predicate = NSPredicate (format: "name == %@", searchString!)
        do
        {
            let result = try context.fetch(request)
            if result.count > 0
            {
                let   n = (result[0] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "name") as! String
                let p = (result[0] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "password") as! String
                //  print(" checking")


                if (searchString == n && searcghstring2 == p)
                {
                    let UserDetailsVc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "UserDetailsViewController") as! UserDetailsViewController
                    UserDetailsVc.myStringValue = nameTextCheck.text
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(UserDetailsVc, animated: true)
                }
                else if (searchString == n || searcghstring2 == p)
                {
                    // print("password incorrect ")
                    let alertController1 = UIAlertController (title: "no user found ", message: "password incorrect ", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                    alertController1.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
                    present(alertController1, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
            else
            {
                let alertController1 = UIAlertController (title: "no user found ", message: "invalid username ", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                alertController1.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
                present(alertController1, animated: true, completion: nil)
                print("no user found")
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            print("error")
        }
    }
}
```

Create SignUpVc

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
class SignUpViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var nameText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var passwordText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var ageText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var emailText: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
          }
      @IBAction func SignUPAction(_ sender: Any) {
        if isValidInput(Input: nameText.text!)
        {
            if isPasswordValid(passwordText.text!)
            {
                if isValidEmail(testStr: emailText.text!)
                {
                        let _:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate)
                        let context:NSManagedObjectContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
                            let newUser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "User", into: context) as NSManagedObject
                        newUser.setValue(nameText.text, forKey: "name")
                        newUser.setValue(passwordText.text, forKey: "password")
                        newUser.setValue(emailText.text, forKey: "email")
                        newUser.setValue(ageText.text, forKey: "age")
                        do {
                            try context.save()
                        } catch {}
                        print(newUser)
                        print("Object Saved.")
                       let alertController1 = UIAlertController (title: "Valid ", message: "Sucess ", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                        alertController1.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
                        present(alertController1, animated: true, completion: nil)


                        let UserDetailsVc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "logoutViewController") as! logoutViewController

                        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(UserDetailsVc, animated: true)

                    }else
                {
                    print("mail check")
                    let alertController1 = UIAlertController (title: "Fill Email id", message: "Enter valid email", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

                    alertController1.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
                    present(alertController1, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
            else
            {
                print("pswd check")
                let alertController1 = UIAlertController (title: "Fill the password ", message: "Enter valid password", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                alertController1.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
                present(alertController1, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
        else
        {
            print("name check")

            let alertController1 = UIAlertController (title: "Fill the Name ", message: "Enter valid username", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

            alertController1.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
            present(alertController1, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
        func isValidInput(Input:String) -> Bool
        {
        let RegEx = "\\A\\w{3,18}\\z"
        let Test = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", RegEx)
        return Test.evaluate(with: Input)
        }
    func isPasswordValid(_ password : String) -> Bool{
        let passwordTest = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[$@$#!%*?&])[A-Za-z\\d$@$#!%*?&]{3,}")
        return passwordTest.evaluate(with: password)
    }
    func isValidEmail(testStr:String) -> Bool {
        // print("validate calendar: \(testStr)")
        let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,}"

        let emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)
        return emailTest.evaluate(with: testStr)
    }
}
```

Create UserDetailsVC

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
class UserDetailsViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var nameText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var ageText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var emailText: UITextField!
    var context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    var myStringValue : String?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
     }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        showData()
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
    func showData()
    {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "User")
        request.predicate = NSPredicate (format: "name == %@", myStringValue!)
        do
        {
            let result = try context.fetch(request)
            if result.count > 0
            {
                let nameData = (result[0] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "name") as! String
                let agedata = (result[0] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "age") as! String
                let emaildata = (result[0] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "email") as! String
                nameText.text = nameData
                ageText.text = agedata
                emailText.text = emaildata
            }
        }
        catch {
            //handle error
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```